# Creating mysql Function with parameters

Tags: mysql, function, parameters

```
delimeter //
DROP function IF EXISTS get_seq_next//
create function get_seq_next(
IN sequence_ref_ varchar(30)
) returns int(11) unsigned
BEGIN
    DECLARE seq_val_  int(11) unsigned;
    LOCK TABLE ga_seq_tab WRITE;
    select sequence_no into seq_val_ from ga_seq_tab where sequence_ref=sequence_ref_;
    if not seq_val_ is null then
        update ga_seq_tab set sequence_no=sequence_no+1 where sequence_ref=sequence_ref_;
    end if
    UNLOCK TABLES;
    return seq_val;
END //
DELIMETER ;
```

I'm trying to create a function but it keeps saying I have syntax errors and I am not sure what is wrong with it

Comment: please post the error. one problem is that you've misspelled `delimiter`

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN sequence_ref_ varchar(30)
) returns int(11) unsigned
BEGIN
    DECLARE seq_va' at line 2 

(I don't have the delimiter fields there when posting it as I am doing so through phpmyadmin (field that specifies it for me))

Comment: I removed the "IN" and I got further, I guess all parameters are IN parameters in a function

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `IN` reserved word in the parameters list.